# Installing SublimeREPL offline

Tags: python, sublimerepl

I'm trying to install SublimeREPL on an offline computer (it has secure data and so can't be Internet-connected). Any ideas for how to do so?

I can copy any installation files to a USB drive, but haven't found any--everywhere I've seen insists on using the Package Manager (which requires connection to function properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try download and install SublimeREPL using Package Control on a computer with an internet connection and then in Sublime Text go to preferences > Browse packages… where you should find a folder named SublimeREPL. Copy that folder to the same directory on the other computer. That should work.

Comment: I have SublimeREPL on my Linux computer, and the destination computer runs Windows; is this going to cause issues? Or should I make sure to pull out the packages folder from a Windows computer?

Comment: Just to be safe, fetch the files from a computer running Windows. If it works SublimeREPL should be visible automatically as described: http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ however there might be issues becuase package control is not installed. Give it a shot.

Comment: I did get package control installed (there's an offline install guide here: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation ); now I just need to find a computer running windows that doesn't have administrative controls against .exes. thanks!